# Force Google App Engine IP refresh

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to force a Google App Engine app IP address renewal.
I can only find threads about how to make it static, but I need to do the opposite for security purposes.

I have tried to automatically remove the instances serving my app, but it seems that the old IP is taken by the instance replacing it.
Maybe it's not possible, anyway, does anybody have a clue on the IP change frequency for a service?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the results you want you'd need to move to [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/?hl=en), as it's not something App Engine can provide currently, but note that they're vastly different products, so it may be some undertaking.

On Compute Engine, you can change the external IP of an instance by [modifying it's configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign). Also [deleting and recreating the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/restarting-an-instance#using_other_restart_methods) likely will have a new IP address associated to it as it's potentially a different machine, but it's not 100% guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks Stu, I had the result i needed using Preemptible Vms and cron tasks .